# Does the .NET MAUI Map function work on the Windows Machine emulator?

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

On the Android emulator it opens Google Maps, on the windows machine it doesn't seem to do anything but also doesn't throw an error. Just wondering if this is a working feature before I waste time.

Thanks.

Comment: according to the docs it does, but does Windows have a map app?

Comment: That's the question. I don't know if it is supposed to open Bing! or something

Answer (score 0):

I installed Microsoft Maps and now the MAUI app interacts with it.